# Django-printing of random values

Tags: django, django-views

I want that the random number generated should be printed on the webpage, ie via `HttpResponse(x)` after every 5 seconds, for which I have used the `time.sleep` function.

How do I print the randomly generated values without refreshing the page?

Here is my **view.py** file

```
def main(request):
    return render(request,'graphs/index.html')

def random_generator(request):
    return HttpResponse(randrange(0, 5))
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'random/','apps.graph.views.main', name = 'graph_home'),
    url(r'random_gen/','apps.graph.views.random_generator', name = 'random'),
)
```

**Template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function refreshRandom() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'random/',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#random').html(data);
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        window.setTimeout(refreshRandom, 5000);
                    }
                });
            }

            window.setTimeout(refreshRandom, 5000);
        </script>    
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='random'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a view for the main page, and another view that returns a random number. Then you write an ajax call in javascript to refresh what you see. Like this:

views.py

```
def main(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def random_generator(request):
    return HttpResponse(randrange(0, 5))
```

urls.py

```
url('^main/$', 'myapp.views.main'),
url('^random/$', 'myapp.views.random_generator')
```

Then in your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshRandom() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/random/',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#random').html(data);
        },
        complete: function() {
            window.setTimeout(refreshRandom, 5000);
        }
    });
}

window.setTimeout(refreshRandom, 5000);
</script>
<div id='random'></div>
```

Though I don't really see what would you gain by doing this through a django view. If that's all you want to do, you might want to try and write the whole thing on the client side with javascript.

Comment: To which view do I set my url to?? `index` view or the `random_generator` view?

Comment: Currently it is `url(r'home/','apps.graph.views.WHICH VIEW'),`

Comment: `url(r'random/', 'apps.graph.views.random_generator')`

Comment: `'str' object has no attribute 'META'` in `return render('graphs/index.html') `. Whats this?

Comment: My index.html file is kept under `/templates/graphs/index.html`

Comment: You want the url '/random/' to be linked to the random_generator view and what I wrote is the main one. I'm not sure as to the error you're seeing seems to be a different problem, I'll play around with it and come back to you

Comment: It should be `return render(request, 'graphs/index.html')`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/

Comment: Oh yeah sorry my bad. I just usually use render_to_response so I forgot

Comment: Well, I'm not able to understand it clearly. My question is when I'm linking the `main` view with the `random/` url , then how come `random_generator` view is getting called?? PS: I'm not able to get the desired results yet.

Comment: Well I'm editing my question. Kindly review and rectify it according. Thanks

Comment: Well, I got it. I was being a noob. I needed to add the `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` . Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure JS to achieve it, no need to bother Django:

```
var random_interval = setInterval(function() {
    var random_number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $('#random-number').text(random_number);
}, 5000); // every 5 second
```

Comment: Well, as per my problem, It requires values to be fetched from backend. This is just a sample problem. Thanks Anyways !!!

Comment: Well I'm editing my question. Kindly review and rectify it according. Thanks